# Pin a program to the taskbar using Advanced Installer

Tags: java, advanced-installer

I am using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html)

to create the installer of my java desktop application, Looking for a solution to pin the main application shortcut to the task bar of window 7

Comment: I dont think this is possible, AFAIK Its something the user decides to do not the programmer, you may ask the user if he wishes to have a desktop shortcut and set one on the desktop if desired.

Comment: @O.D But we can add .exe to quick launch of windows XP using installer, and that is quit same thing... this is required to pin it in the task-bar :(

Comment: im not sure about using the installer, but you could also do it using some windows native scripts (batch or vbs)

Comment: Im not sure, and i dont really know the installer you mentioned, but i would find it wierd if i as a user install a programm which sets me a shortcut on the taskbar. as saied maby Im wrong ... good luck!

Comment: This is also a good converter http://www.favicon.cc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O.D. is right, [Microsoft does not recommend automatic pinning](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185512/Programmatically-PIN-shortcut-onto-Taskbar-on-Win7) in the task bar for Win 7, this is why the feature was never implemented in Advanced Installer. However, pinning if possible programmatically, as you can see in the linked article. All you have to do is to add your code as a custom action at the end of the install process, so the shortcuts can be pinned after the installer creates them.